# SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm learning stored procedure and facing some problems.

My question is,

I've written insert and update queries in a SP as below,

```
create proc pateintupdate
(
@regno int,
@regdate datetime,
@pname varchar(30),
@fhname varchar(30),
@paddress varchar(75),
@city varchar(20),
@mnum varchar(14),
@gender varchar(8),
@mstatus varchar(15),
@age int
)
as
begin
insert into patiententry(regno,regdate,name,fname,address,city,mnum,gender,mstatus,age) values(@regno,@regdate,@pname,@fhname,@paddress,@city,@mnum,@gender,@mstatus,@age);

update patiententry set regdate=@regdate,name=@pname,fname=@fhname,address=@paddress,city=@city,mnum=@mnum,gender=@gender,mstatus=@mstatus,age=@age where regno=@regno
end
```

and I need to access these queries from Data Layer with stored procedure OUT parameters.

How can I access above two queries?

Comment: In your data layer what are you using for database access? Also, before you can access OUTPUT parameters in a stored procedure you need to define some.

Comment: Sir,actually i'm using nothing in data layer,i

Comment: I think it's clear that you don't actually know what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

@age int,
 @PK_New int output
)

set @PK_New = scope_identity()

in the stored procedure.

- 
- 

command.Parameters.Add("@PK_New", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@PK_New"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

int recordsAffected = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteNonQuery());

int recordId = Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["@PK_New"].Value);

in the C# application.